# Reference values in Excel Tables with a semantic reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup, named-ranges

### Problem

I have an Excel Table Object:

[image]

In which I store assumptions for a formula.

**Are there best practices for referencing a value in that table with a semantic reference?**

### Deeper Explanation

#### Attempt #1: Good old referencing

Let's say that I need to calculate the product of B2 and B3.

```
=$B$2*$B$3
```

This solution is not very robust - what if someone copypastes something or moves the table? There must be a better way!

#### Attempt #2: VLOOKUP

I could create a VLOOKUP. This is not too robust: If the name of the value changes, this will fail. Also, if I want to get the product of 5 table-values, I would need to create an unreadable formula with 5 VLOOKUPs inside!

```
=VLOOKUP("Lambda Requests per Month [Requests/Month]";Table145[[#All];[Name]:[Value]];2;FALSE)
```

#### Attempt #3: Named Ranges

[image]

and reference it like this:

```
=Lambda_Requests_per_Month__Requests_Month
```

This works, but now I can't easily tell the units in the formula. And units containing special characters, let's say [%], vanish completely.

**Is there any better way?**

Comment: You posit a situation where the location of the table can change, and also the name of the variable may change.  What will be remaining constant?  If the row number is constant, you can refer to the nth row of the table using `INDEX` function.  Or you could use `VLOOKUP` with a wild card depending on how much the variable name might change.  Please construct a data example (as text) and information to reproduce your possible issue.

Comment: A point well argued. I have now decided that named ranges are the way to go, as they are robust to changing cell references and update well

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use named ranges, and use a script that changes the NamedRanges name.

It expects a name column, and to its right a value column. To use it, select the value column and run the VBA macro.

```vb
Sub rename_name_manager()
'Written by Dustin
'Adds references and names to the NameManager, iff a reference does not yet exist with a name in the name manager.
'If a reference already exists, the name is updated with the value stored to the left of the cell
'Names have to be sanitized first, i.e. only alphabet, number, _ is allowed. No space!

'Create a dictionary, in which the NameManagers cell-references are stored.
Dim d
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    d.Add n.RefersTo, n.Name
Next n


Dim wksname As String
wksname = "'YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME'"

Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In Selection
    reference_in_NameManager = "=" & wksname & "!" & cl.Address
    If d.exists(reference_in_NameManager) Then
        'already exists in NameManager, only need to rename
        name_ = cl.Offset(0, -1).Value2
           
        'Sanitize string
        name_ = Replace(name_, "$", "USD")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "%", "Percent")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "/", "_")
        name_ = Replace(name_, " ", "_")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "___", "_")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "__", "_")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "-", "")
        name_ = Replace(name_, ",", "_")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "[", "__")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "]", "_")
        name_ = Replace(name_, "(", "__")
        name_ = Replace(name_, ")", "_")
        If Right(name_, 1) = "_" Then
            name_ = Left(name_, Len(name_) - 1)
        End If
        
        'Rename the name in NameManager
        Names.Item(RefersTo:=reference_in_NameManager).Name = name_
        
        
    Else
        'Not yet referenced in NameManager. Create new Name
        Debug.Print "="&wksname&"!" & cl.Address
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=name_, RefersTo:="=" & wksname & "!" & cl.Address
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Names(name_).Comment = ""
    End If
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of relying on Selection, might be more robust to refer to the list object columns by name. Assuming the column headers are not something that also changes.